# FFmpeg is in Path, but running in the CMD results in "FFmpeg not recognized as internal or external command"

Tags: python, ffmpeg, path

FFmpeg is installed in `C:\FFmpeg`, and I put `C:\FFmpeg\bin` in the path. Does anyone know how to fix?
Thanks!

Comment: Run `set` in the terminal. What do you get?

Comment: You must didn't add `FFmpeg` to your system PATH.

Comment: @Omer This is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/eH2R6azu

Comment: You have added C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe; this in path replace it C:\FFmpeg\bin\ directory without ffmpeg.exe

Answer (score -1):

You added `C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe` to your path, instead, you need to add only the directory:
`C:\FFmpeg\bin\`

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: The pastebin link you posted shows that `C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe` is in your PATH. That is WRONG. You need `C:\FFmpeg\bin\` to be in your path. The directory. NOT the executable.